# How to bypass Facebook "Social Reader"-type apps, to view content without installing?

Tags: google-chrome, facebook, greasemonkey

In Facebook, some links to articles or videos appear to be genuine links, but in fact there are leading to some "content viewing" Facebook apps, like "Dailymotion", "The Guardian", or "Yahoo!". Those apps usually require access to my email address, basic info, birthday, location, plus right to post on my behalf. Some even say in small letters "To use this app, you will be upgraded to Facebook Timeline":

[image: Dailymotion fake link]

Workaround:

1. Copy the name of the article/video
2. Paste it into Google within quotes
3. First result is the original unencumbered content.

I don't want to install Facebook spyapps that provide zero value, so I do this every time.

**QUESTION:**Is there a Greasemonkey script or similar, that would perform these 3 steps for me?

I am using Chrome on Linux.

*I hesitated to post this question on WebApps, but over there they are clear that [such questions should be posted on SuperUser](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/are-questions-about-browsers-accepted-as-long-as-they-are-related-to-using-a-web).*

Comment: If you simply wanted to hide the endless stream of spam and apps, I'd recommend the [F.B. Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/) userscript/extension!

Comment: @iglvzx: That could be a better-than-nothing solution, but something that would replace links would be the best.

Comment: Nicolas, which operating system?

Comment: @iglvzx: Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Please link to some examples of these links.  Depending on the details, it might be easy to write a script, but I haven't seen a link like this yet. (I avoid Facebook AMAP.)

Comment: @iglvzx the latest version of FB Purity actually has an option to fix those redirect links

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're running chrome, there's [Facebook Unsocial Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lbdpfpcjdacpjajeiinhbbgdahbdgdbh) that will fix those links

> **Rewrites Facebook Social Reader links to just be links and not require you to install.**
>
> Facebook Unsocial Reader rewrites Facebook's Social Reader links to just be Google "I'm feeling lucky" searches for the article's title. Now you don't need to install an app and provide your demographic information to the publisher of the content for content that's free anyway.

Comment: This one seems to be similar: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/decpifcgghgmmikfakpkjipmigknbflk

Comment: Also: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/opigjeobmencoghohonhabhmgaadlepe

Comment: a god among men.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of the FB Purity browser extension (compatible with Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera) has a built in option for fixing these redirect links, see here: http://www.fbpurity.com

Answer (score 3):

Some apps that ask if you would give permission to post on your behalf, or use your email, sometimes you can deny this esp. if it is a reputable company or trying to be (Yahoo, etc) and still get through without consequence. Not really a "best answer" but a work around if need be.

Comment: Indeed, pressing "Cancel" still leads to the article, at least in some cases, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I created a user script for Greasemonkey which does this after not finding a good solution for Firefox. It works in Chrome too. You can find it on [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/132594) on userscripts.org.

Answer (score 0):

I know for a fact that with links to The Guardian if you attach `?fb=native` to the end of the link, it will direct the link to the proper page and not the social reader app page.